# Django 1.4 on App Engine with SQL Cloud

Tags: django, google-app-engine, djangoappengine

Anyone was successful with Django 1.4 and Google App Engine? I have finished my project, which I was going to upload on App Engine, and I realised that currently newest supported version is 1.3 of GAE SDK is 1.3. Any ideas what should I do now? Does downgrade to 1.3 is a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can include the 1.4 'django' folder in your project like a library.  I'm not sure if it's considered a good practice, but that's what I'm doing and it's been working fine.